# Column Formatting in Python

Tags: python

How would you format this is Python.

```
print("Rating", "\t", "Number of Processors")
print("*",processor_count1)
print("**", processor_count2)
print("***", processor_count3)
```

The result when you run it is this:

```
Rating   Number of Processors
* 1
** 3
*** 1
```

As you can see the numbers are not lined up with the title. The duplicate answer does not help at at all

Comment: Or any of the numerous other questions on aligning text in Python. Learn to search!

Comment: Formulate it very clearly. "Does not help at all" is nothing. Explain, why your question is different as the duplicate, extend it if it is needed. Unfortunately, even so you will have only a small chance for a reopen.

Comment: *"The duplicate answer does not help at at all"* - neither does adding that. Please **be specific**. Or just do some research.